How to give gradient in stacked column chart in Amcharts4 graph
Sample Image
Here's an inline link to Codepen
I tried amcharts4 gradient feature to give shades to each column. I have attached the codepen. I am expecting that each stacked column should have shades of their colour. Suppose that Follow up completed has green color then all the values in it have different shades of green.
